# So this function is weird.

Tags: graphing-functions

In the Desmos graphing calculator, I plugged in the equation $x^y=y^x$, and this appears.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zxCJ.png

I know that the red line represents the entire function, but honestly, calling it two lines seems pretty reasonable to me. So, first question. If you look at the two other functions, they meet at coordinates (e,e). This also happens to be where the two red lines meet. The first question is why e, out of all numbers.

Or, at least, they *seem* to converge there. Zoom in far enough and you get these.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmcOq.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVEUG.png

Explanations, anyone?

Comment: Don't believe what you see when zooming. You are just at the limit of accuracy of Desmos. The true curve is smooth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the logarithm, the equation can be rewritten

$$\frac {\ln x}x=\frac {\ln y}y.$$

Let $f(x):=\dfrac{\ln x}x$. This function is not invertible, but can be split in two invertible sections, which are separated by a maximum, at

$$f'(x)=\frac1{x^2}-\frac{\ln x}{x^2}=0,$$ i.e. $x=e$. The is where $e$ appears. The complete graph of the curve is given by the two functions

$$y=f_<^{-1}\left(f(x)\right)=f_<^{-1}\left(\frac {\ln x}x\right)$$and $$y=f_>^{-1}\left(f(x)\right)=f_>^{-1}\left(\frac {\ln x}x\right)$$ where the subscripts denote the two branches.

Observe that

$$x<e\implies y=f_<^{-1}\left(\frac {\ln x}x\right)=x$$ and $$x>e\implies y=f_>^{-1}\left(\frac {\ln x}x\right)=x$$ and this corresponds to the linear part. The curvy part corresponds to the reversed inequalities.

Now you can undertand why the double point is found at $x=y=e$.

---

For a better understanding, let us consider a similar situation, starting from

$$x^2-2x=y^2-2y.$$

This time we can invert $f(x)=x^2-2x$, using

$$z=f(y)=y^2-2y\iff y=f_{</>}^{-1}(z)=1\pm\sqrt{1+z}.$$

From this, with $z=x^2-2x$,

$$y=1\pm\sqrt{x^2-2x+1}=1\pm(x-1).$$ we have the two straight lines $y=x$ and $y=2-x$. By intersection, the double point is $x=y=1$.

Notice that the maximum of $f(x)$ is achieved for $x=1$, where the two branches meet.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the line $y=x$ is valid as a solution to this equation as
$$x^y=y^x \implies x^x=x^x$$ 
The other curve of this graph is given by the parametric equation
$$x=t^{\frac1{t-1}}$$ 
$$y=t^{\frac{t}{t-1}}$$
where $t$ is an arbitrary parameter which can be used to find any other point on the curve. For example, if $t=3$ we get the point
$$x=3^{\frac12}=\sqrt{3}$$
$$y=3^{\frac32}=3\sqrt{3}$$
$$\therefore (\sqrt{3})^{3\sqrt{3}}=(3\sqrt{3})^{\sqrt{3}}$$

Comment: What do the three dots denote?

Comment: Three dots mean "therefore"